# Supervising coroutines in Lua

Tags: lua, coroutine

I have written a code that runs multiple tasks one after the other in Lua. There is simply a loop that calls each function and then use the output for the next one and so on.
Usually there is no issue, but it happens that there is some error. In these situations the code would just stop working.

What I want is to monitor my code. In case there is an error at some point, I can call plan B and avoid that the program interrupts.

I've read about Lua coroutines, and it appears to be what i am looking for. If there is an error, the coroutine returns the error.

My question is whether I can stop coroutine that last too long. Lua offers asynchronous coroutines, so I thought that I cannot execute a function and simultaneously compute how long it has been busy doing the task. Am I getting this right, or is there a way to basically stop coroutines from the outside with some condition ?

Thank you

Comment: don't you just want pcall? No, there isn't a way to stop something that runs too long

Comment: You can set a hook on a coroutine to monitor how many lines of code are executed, and raise an error from inside the hook to stop a very long coroutine.

Comment: The program interacts with external device (sensors), and so it happens that it got suck because there's no response from the sensor. I won't be adble to see this with counting the numbers of lines.

Comment: Remove the multithreading tag, [lua is designed for single-threading](https://lua-users.org/wiki/ThreadsTutorial), if you need real multithreading, implement it in the host language, or ask the API provider to add a timeout parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using Lua coroutines. Lua coroutines are *cooperative*; they do not (inherently) support *preemption*, which is what you're looking for. For a coroutine to return execution to the caller of `coroutine.resume`, it has to "cooperate" by calling `coroutine.yield` or `error`.

As has been pointed out in the comments, it is possible to set a line hook - or even an "instruction hook" - to implement preemption of Lua-only code, by interrupting the code on every new line / every couple instructions executed and checking whether a timeout is met.

This stops working as soon as you call a (blocking) C function, including Lua standard library functions; it only works well for "pure Lua" code which only does constant-time API calls, since the API call is just a single line of code / instruction for Lua; Lua has no view "into" the function.

To solve this issue, you'll need actual multithreading e.g. using [lualanes](https://lualanes.github.io/lanes/), multiprocessing (e.g. using [luaposix's fork](http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/examples/fork.lua.html)), or a nonblocking API and polling.

Comment: Would a process running in a bash file cope for this ? I have written a file, but I remark that the lua program and the bash process are not concurrent. Is there a particular reason why this happen ? Thank you

Comment: @cobdmg spawning / executing processes is by default blocking and synchronous: If you run Lua from bash (e.g. `lua myfile.lua`), Bash will wait until the Lua process has terminated before it continues execution. Similarly, if you execute Bash from Lua (e.g. `os.execute"/bin/bash mybash.sh`), Lua will wait until Bash is done running.

On the Bash side of things, you can use `&` to run something concurrently ("in the background"): `lua myfile.lua &` will spawn a background process. On the Lua side of things, you'd need something like `luaposix`.